# how to maintain the appearance of the tiled map when I change the resolution in libGDX

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, tiled, tmxtiledmap

i have created a test tiled map for a 2D game that i am programming. And everything is fine with!, but when i change the resolution the camera doesn´t fit the screen correctly.

I have a player sprite and the Tile map, and I use a resolution of 1366x768, as you can see the screen fit correctly:

[image]

but when i change the resolution, for example 640x480. The player doesn´t fit according to the new resolution as you can see in this picture:

[image]

The player seems bigger, but i want to fit the entire screen according to the new resolution, including all the sprites.

I think there is a problem with the cam rendering, but i don´t know what can i do to solve it. The camera is following the player movement and everything is ok with that, but i want to fit the screen game with the resolutions selected.

I'll put some parts of my code for you can see:

Here is the main code:

```
public class codeTiled implements ApplicationListener {

... //Variables.....

public void create() {      
    manager = new AssetManager();
    manager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader());
    manager.load("C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/tilemap/TiledMap/data/maps/test.tmx", TiledMap.class);
    manager.finishLoading();
    map = manager.get("C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/tilemap/TiledMap/data/maps/test.tmx", TiledMap.class);
    batch=new SpriteBatch();
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(50, 50 * (h / w));

    float unitScale = 1 / 8f;
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, unitScale);
    player=new playerEx(100, 100, camera);
}

public void render() {      
    handleInput();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();
    batch.begin();
    player.render(batch);
    batch.end();
}

private void handleInput() {

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ESCAPE)){
        System.exit(0);
    }
     camera.zoom = MathUtils.clamp(camera.zoom, 0.1f, 100/camera.viewportWidth);
    float effectiveViewportWidth = camera.viewportWidth * camera.zoom;
    float effectiveViewportHeight = camera.viewportHeight * camera.zoom;
    camera.position.x = MathUtils.clamp(camera.position.x, effectiveViewportWidth / 2f, 100 - effectiveViewportWidth / 2f);
    camera.position.y = MathUtils.clamp(camera.position.y, effectiveViewportHeight / 2f, 100 - effectiveViewportHeight / 2f);
}
```

And this is some part of my player class:

```
public class playerEx {

...//Variables....

public playerEx(int x, int y, OrthographicCamera camera){
    this.camera=camera;
    recP= new Rectangle();
    recP.height = 64;
    recP.width = 64;
    recP.x = x;
    recP.y = y;

    imagen=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/tilemap/TiledMap/data/sprites/player/minigunattack.png"));
    imagen2=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/tilemap/TiledMap/data/sprites/player/minigunstand.png")); 
    TextureRegion[][] tmp=TextureRegion.split(imagen,
            imagen.getWidth()/5,imagen.getHeight());
    imagen1=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/tilemap/TiledMap/data/sprites/player/feet.png"));
    TextureRegion[][] tmp1=TextureRegion.split(imagen1,
            imagen1.getWidth()/5,imagen1.getHeight());
    movPlayer=new TextureRegion[5];
    movFeet=new TextureRegion[5];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        movFeet[i]=tmp1[0][i];
    }for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        movPlayer[i]=tmp[0][i];
    }animationAttack=new Animation(0.08f,movPlayer);
    animationFeet=new Animation(0.10f,movFeet);
    tiempo=0f;                                                                                                                
}
```

Again, the camera is programmed to follow the player and it works fine. But when i want to change it to another resolution the sprite player doesn´t fit with the tiled map :(.

Hope somebody can help me with this...
Thank you!.

Comment: you forget `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);`

Comment: If i put that the player's sprite gets bigger and it fills on the entire screen :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use a viewport and some Constants values for your world.

Firstly we define a default screen width and height in pixel. Doesn't matter how big the end screen will be.
In my example, I say the default screen size is: 512x256 pixel.

Secondly, I must decide how many pixels are one Meter. So if I say 256 pixels is one meter, my viewport shows 2x1 meter of my world. That's very small. If I want that my viewport shows for example 16 meter I can calculate: 512 / 16 = Pixel_Per_Meter. In this case 32.

Finally, we create a `Constants` class:

```
public class Constants {

    public static final float PPM = 32; // PPM = Pixel per Meter
    public static final float MPP = 1 / PPM; // MPP = Meter per Pixel

    public static final int WORLD_PIXEL_WIDTH = 512;
    public static final int WORLD_PIXEL_HEIGHT = 256;
    public static final float WORLD_WIDTH = WORLD_PIXEL_WIDTH / PPM; //in meter
    public static final float WORLD_HEIGHT = WORLD_PIXEL_HEIGHT / PPM; //in meter
}
```

Now when you see later in your game, the shown world is too small or too big, you can change the `WORLD_PIXEL_WIDTH` and `WORLD_PIXEL_HEIGHT` to show more or less

Now we create our `OrthographicCamera`, `FitViewport` and `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer`

> Viewport is a very important part of the game. If you will know more about Viewports read the viewport part of
>   [calling render method from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137023/calling-render-method-from-another-class/53151274#53151274) and [Libgdx set ortho camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011592/libgdx-set-ortho-camera/52059981#52059981)

So first create our `OrthographicCamera` 'camera' and our `FitViewport` 'viewport'

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
viewport = new FitViewport(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH, Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);
camera.position.set(viewport.getWorldWidth() / 2, viewport.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0); // Differ from your I eat ann Apple
```

Then our `SpriteBatch` 'batch' and `TiledMap` 'map'

```
batch = new SpriteBatch();
map = app.getAssets().loadSingleAsset("map/" + level + ".tmx", TiledMap.class);
```

And finally, our `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer` 'mapRenderer'

```
mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, Constants.MPP);
```

To render our world:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    camera.update();

    mapRenderer.setView(camera);
    mapRenderer.render();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    player.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the tutorial. With your explanation i have solved my problem. Thank you!.